# How can I check if a string with a comma is bigger than 232.68

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input with a decimal number (comma used instead of a dot):

```
<input id="amount" name="amount" maxlength="7" type="text" value="0,00" />
```

I want to check if the amount is higher than 232.68

I tested:

```
    $('#amount').change(function(){
var myamount = parseFloat($("#amount").text().replace(',', '.'));
    if(myamount > 232.68){
        alert("The amount is too high!");
     } 
})
```

1. I want to replace the comma with a dot only in the var
2. I want to check if the amount is higher than 232.68
3. I want to alert if it is higher than 232.68

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Inputs have a value, not text.

Comment: @undefined A self-closing tag has no `.text()` but since it is a textbox it does have a `.val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#amount').change(function(){
var myamount = parseFloat($("#amount").val().replace(',', '.'));
    if(myamount > 232.68){
        alert("The amount is too high!");
     } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use val() instead of text()

```
$('#amount').change(function(){
var myamount = parseFloat($("#amount").val().replace(',', '.'));
    if(myamount > 232.68){
        alert("The amount is too high!");
     } 
})
```